# How to Delete Selected Items in ListView C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

The problem is after removing a list item from the list,but whenever the user tries to enter another list item, the deleted item returns back to the list.

I am really new to c#. Any help is very much appreciated. 
This is my code.

```
 int index = 0;
  string [,] item = new string[10000,10];


private void add() // THIS IS FOR THE ADD BUTTON
        {
            item[index, 0] = maskID.Text;
            item[index, 1] = txtLName.Text;
            item[index, 2] = txtFName.Text;
            item[index, 3] = maskContact.Text;
            item[index, 4] = txtAddress.Text;
            item[index, 5] = cmbCourse.Text;
            item[index, 6] = cmbYear.Text;
            index++

            listDorm.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            {
                ListViewItem word = new ListViewItem();
                word.Text = item[i, 0];
                word.SubItems.Add(item[i, 1]);
                word.SubItems.Add(item[i, 2]);
                word.SubItems.Add(item[i, 3]);
                word.SubItems.Add(item[i, 4]);
                word.SubItems.Add(item[i, 5]);
                word.SubItems.Add(item[i, 6]);
                listDorm.Items.Add(word);

                Clear(); //THIS IS TO CLEAR ALL THE TEXTBOXES IN REGISTRATION FORM
            }
        }
         private void Delete() //THIS IS FOR DELETING ITEMS
        {
            DialogResult delItem;

            delItem = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this?", "Remove Item", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

            if (delItem == DialogResult.Yes)

                    listDorm.Items.RemoveAt(listDorm.SelectedIndices[0]);
                    Clear();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Under the code for the remove button, you should also remove the item from the array `item`.